# Zipline Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, zipline, back-testing

I'd like to automate my manual trading strategies. However, for the beginning, I tried to reproduce Zipline's simple example of buying Apple stocks. I struggled running the algorithm with `run_algorithm()`. When I was trying to run the 'dual moving average cross', the exact same error came up. I also tried IPython and Terminal but still get that error. I couldn't find anything related to that either in this forum. I would very grateful for any hints. Thank you.

I'm using Python 3.6 on macOS and Zipline version 1.1.1.

That's the code:

```
import zipline as zl from zipline.api import order, record, symbol


def initialize(context):
    pass


def handle_data(context, data):
    order(symbol('AAPL'), 10)
    record(AAPL=data.current(symbol('AAPL'), 'price'))

zl.run_algorithm(start='2015-1-1', end='2017-1-1', initialize=initialize, capital_base=10000)
```

That's the traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/SOL/Desktop/Python/backtest.py", line 13, in
>   zl.run_algorithm(start=2015-1-1, end=2017-1-1, initialize=initialize,
>   capital_base=10000) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/utils/run_algo.py",
>   line 360, in run_algorithm environ=environ, File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/utils/run_algo.py",
>   line 132, in _run env = TradingEnvironment(asset_db_path=connstr,
>   environ=environ) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/finance/trading.py",
>   line 99, in init self.bm_symbol, File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/data/loader.py",
>   line 173, in load_market_data environ, File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/data/loader.py",
>   line 287, in ensure_treasury_data if not has_data_for_dates(data,
>   first_date, last_date): File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/data/loader.py",
>   line 87, in has_data_for_dates dts = series_or_df.index
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I think the problem has to do with **SSL** certificates in **python 3.6**. Unfortunately the error message (especially if you ignore the stack trace) is not very helpful. For mac try:
`sudo /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates`command
to reinstall the certificates

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://www.zipline.io/appendix.html#zipline.run_algorithm) here, `start` and `end` are `datetime` objects, and not strings. So, You should define those as following:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=1)
end = datetime(year=2017, month=1, day=1)
```

and then call

```
zl.run_algorithm(start=start, end=end, initialize=initialize, capital_base=10000)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it but still get the same error message...